# cake php, undefined variable problem

Tags: php, cakephp

i have a controller page like this:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
var $helpers = array ('Html','Form');
var $name = 'Users';

function index() {
    $this->set('view_users', $this->User->find('all'));
}
}
```

then i have another controller page like this:

```
    class PostsController extends AppController {
var $helpers = array ('Html','Form');
var $name = 'Posts';

function index() {
    $this->set('edit_users', $this->Post->find('all'));
}
}
```

then i have the index file:

```
<?php foreach($view_users as $value): ?>
<p>id - <?php echo $value['User']['first']; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php foreach($edit_users as $value): ?>
<p>id - <?php echo $value['Post']['first']; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the problem i get is :`Notice (8): Undefined variable: view_users [APP\views\posts\index.ctp, line 6]`

very strange since the `edit_users` var works.

What can be the problem?
thanks

Comment: Is the "index file" the same for both controller actions?

Comment: yes, i want it to be the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UsersController` and the `PostsController` are different controllers. They use different views and even though they both have an `index` action, they are called separately and use different views.

When you go to `/users/index`, it calls the `index` action of the `UsersController` which sets the `$view_users` variable.

When you go to `/posts/index`, it calls in the `index` action of the `PostsController` which sets the `$edit_users`.

**The problem:** You `PostsController` `login` action isn't setting a value for `$view_users` so the variable is undefined. Assuming that you `Post` model has a relationship with the `User` model, you should be able to add this to the `PostsController` `index` action to solve your problem:

```
$this->set('view_users', $this->Post->User->find('all'));
```

Alternatively, you could change the view to use `empty` to check if the variable was set first:

```
if ( ! empty($view_users) )
  foreach ( $view_users as view_user )
  {
    // Do something useful.
  }
```

Comment: thanks for response. however `$this->set('view_users', $this->Post->User->find('all')); ` doesn't work. Isn't there a way to display data from `/users/` and `/posts/` in the same page?

Comment: @Patrioticcow - Yes and no. It depends on what you want to do but you'll have to use the same controller action and create a route. I doubt that's what you want though as that would show the same (identical) view for both. Make sure you have a relationship (belongsTo, hasOne, ...) defined in the `Post` and `User` models if you're going to add the extra line otherwise, it won't work. CakePHP also uses different views for each controller action. It won't use the `/views/index` view for `/users/index` unless you specifically tell it to.

Comment: what i actually want to do is to grab data from 2 tables and display them in the same view. One of the tables is `Users` and another one is `Posts`

Comment: @Patrioticcow - In that case, add `$this->set('view_users', $this->Post->User->find('all'));` to the `index` action of the `PostsController` and make sure that a relationship is defined between the `Post` and `User` models.

Comment: what kind of relationship are you referring to? Is there an example you can point me too? Sorry, im new to this, still building the bases.

Comment: @Patrioticcow - Have a look at [http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together). The `User` model should have link to the `Post` model using a `hasMany` relationship while the `Post` model should link to `User` with a `belongsTo` relationship. The models are in the `./app/models/` folder.